# Bug: perform a diff in Tortoise CVS after a file rename (using CVSNT)?

Tags: diff, cvs, tortoisecvs, cvsnt

I used the experimental feature in Tortoise CVS to rename a file in my CVS repository.  Checkouts and commits work fine for this file, however if I perform a diff in Tortoise I get an error:

```
cvs server: cannot find module `MyModule/NewFileName.DPR' - ignored
```

This is the command that Tortoise CSV uses to perform the checkout during the diff:

```
In C:\...\Temp\TCV22023.tmp: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -q -f 
checkout -r 1.10 -d temp MyModule/MyNewFileName.DPR
CVSROOT=:sspi:user@cvs-server:2401/repo
```

The interesting thing is that browsing the repository files on the server, all of the control files (those ending in ",v" reference OldFileName.DPR instead of NewFileName.DPR).  Which is my thinking on why the above diff command failed.

Any input on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

**CVSNT version:** 2.5.04 (build 3236) 
**TortoiseCVS client:** 1.10.10 (CVSNT client 2.5.03)

Answer (score 1):

The file on the server mantains the name with which it was created, because of the RCS format used by CVS(NT). A file may be renamed on one branch, for example and not everywhere.

There was some bugs in the rename function (see see http://www.cvsnt.org/pipermail/cvsnt/2008-February/030202.html), moreover be aware you have to commit the *directory* when you rename, because the it's the directory that keeps track of renames.